# increasing polynomial graph with two points having slope zero

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, slope

We recently learned about the slope of a polynomial graph, and that an odd-degree graph can be strictly increasing despite having a point with $dy/dx=0$. Example: $x \mapsto x^3.$

i was wondering if there is graph possible with two points having $dy/dx=0$, while remaining injective (one-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works because $0$ is a double root of the derivative of $x^3$.   Take $f'(x) = x^2(x-1)^2 = x^4 -2x^3+ x^2$.  Notice that $f'(x)$ is always positive (because it's a square.)  And note that $f'(0) = f'(1) =0.$

So now just undifferentiate to get $f(x) = x^5/5 - x^4/2 +x^3/3.$

Answer (score 1):

Of *course*!

Why would you think otherwise?

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is interested in the polynomial expression which is graphed here.

Answer (score 1):

Take any postive polynomial with two roots and find the antiderivative of it the antiderivative will be increasing since its derivative is positive and will have two points having slope $0$ .